# Longtable composed of independent tabulars spanning multiple pages

Tags: longtable

I have a multiple-page table composed of independent tabulars. I want to break the long table between the tabulars.

I have used longtable. Is it the right approach ? In any case it does not correctly interact with the colortbl package.

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Any idea how to solve this ? You will find below a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Lightgray}{gray}{.85}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{\bf Table 1} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps & over & the & lazy & dog \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\{ }\\
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Table 2} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
& { }\hspace{3mm}{ } &
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf Table 3} \\\hline
jumps & over & the & lazy & dog \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\\
{ }
\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Table 4} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\
{ }
\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\bf Table 5} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps & over \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\{}\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf Table 6} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\caption{A simple longtable example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{\bf Table 1} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps & over & the & lazy & dog \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[3mm]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Table 2} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf Table 3} \\\hline
jumps & over & the & lazy & dog \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[3mm]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Table 4} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[3mm]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\bf Table 5} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps & over \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\\[3mm]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8} \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\bf Table 6} \\\hline
The & quick & brown & fox & jumps \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: longtable isn't helping at all here you can simply remove it and have the tabulars.

Comment: Indeed, this is the second component in the MWE above using \begin{table} but it does not split the table and put the caption with (cont.) in the next page :-(

Comment: No you don't want `table` either, just the tabular. If you need an overall caption you could use `\captionof{table}{...}` from the capt-of package